# What are the differences between blackheads and whiteheads? Different oils? Or different outcome?

Tags: pores, hair-follicle, sebum-oil

What are the differences between blackheads  and or whiteheads? Are different types of oils (sebaceous) involved? Or are they irritated by different things? Or does one become a pimple? And the other one is more of a blemish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When things like dead skin or cosmetic build-up get into your pores and plug them up, and that pore is still producing its normal amount of sebum, that's when it becomes a whitehead or blackhead. Whiteheads lie below the surface of your skin and blackheads are at the surface.

Both blackheads and whiteheads, says Dr. Chwalek, occur "when a pore gets blocked with dead skin cells and oils." The difference is that in the case of whiteheads the pore remains closed; whereas with blackheads, the pore is stretched open.

http://stylecaster.com/beauty/the-difference-between-blackheads-and-sebaceous-filaments/

http://www.instyle.com/beauty/skin/difference-between-blackheads-and-whiteheads-and-how-treat-them